# Spivak, Question on calculation in Ch. 18: : If $a^x=(\log^{-1}(\log{a}))^x=e^{x\log{a}}$, how do we prove that $a^x$ takes on every positive value?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-explanation, logarithms, exponential-function

I'm following along Chapter 18 "The Logarithm and Exponential Functions" from Spivak's *Calculus*.

**I'll ask my question directly now, and then go through a derivation that motivated my question:**

> If for $a>0$ we define $$a^x=(\log^{-1}(\log{a}))^x=e^{x\log{a}}$$
>
> how do we prove that $a^x$ takes on all values?

To show this I initially tried

let $v$ be any number.

Then $a^x=v\implies e^{x\log(a)}=v\implies e^x=v^{1/\log{a}}\implies x=v^{1/\log{a}}$

However, I am not sure that the operation of raising each side of an expression to the power $1/\log{a}$ is defined yet at this particular point in Spivak's book.

**Here is the reasoning that led me to ask this question**

One of the goals of the chapter is to define the function $a^x$ for any $x$. This is done with an argument based on the fact that if a function $f$ satisfies $$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)\tag{1}$$for rational $x$ and $y$, and $f(1)=a\neq 0$, then $f(x)=a^x, x\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Here is the summary of the argument used to define $a^x$ for all $x$.

Assume we have a differentiable function $f$ satisfying $(1)$ for all $x$ and $y$. If we compute the derivative of such a function, we obtain

$$f'(x)=f'(0)f(x)=\alpha f(x)$$

And assuming $f$ has an inverse $f^{-1}$, using the inverse function theorem we reach

$$(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac{1}{\alpha x}$$

But this tells us a lot about $f^{-1}$. $f^{-1}$ is continuous for $x>0$, and by the FTC1, we have

$$f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}dt$$

At this point we don't know what $\alpha=f'(0)$ is exactly. However, what if $\alpha=1$ for some function $f$? We don't know if it is possible, but let's try to see if it is by defining a function

$$\log{x}=\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}dt$$

At this point we can easily prove some properties that this function $\log{x}$ has

- $x,y>0$ then $\log{xy}=\log{x}+\log{y}$
- $n\in\mathbb{N}, x>0\implies \log{x^n}=n\log{x}$
- $x,y>0$ then $\log{x/y}=\log{x}-\log{y}$

Since $\log'{x}=\frac{1}{x}>0$ for $x>0$, there is an inverse defined on the image of $\log{x}$ which can be shown to be $\mathbb{R}$ since $\log{x}$ is unbounded on $(0,\infty)$.

Also, we can prove that

$$(\log^{-1})'(x)=\log^{-1}(x)$$

and

$$\log^{-1}{(x+y)}=\log^{-1}{x}\cdot\log^{-1}{y}, \text{ for all } x,y$$

Recall that we were looking for a function with this property. We've found it.

Since it has this property, we know that when $x$ is rational, we have

$$\log^{-1}(x)=e^x$$

where $e$ at this point is just some unknown number satisfying $\log^{-1}(1)=e\neq 0$.

But we can set this particular number apart by defining the symbol $e$ as

$$e=\log^{-1}{1}$$

$e^x$ for rational $x$ is defined in specific ways that I won't describe here too deeply: basically, $e^n=e\cdot e ...\cdot e$, $e^0=1$, $e^{-n}=\frac{1}{e^n}$, $e^{1/n}=\sqrt[n]{e}$, and $e^{m/n}=(\sqrt[n]{e})^m$, and these are all definitions that result from the desire to have $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ be true for all rational numbers if $f(x)=e^x$.

What about if $x$ is irrational? In this case we **define** $e^x$ to be the value of the function $\log^{-1}$ evaluated at $x$.

As a result of this definition, $e^x$ is now defined for all numbers $x$. Note that we don't know what number $e$ is exactly, we only know that it exists because we've shown that $\log^{-1}$ exists and is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Also, we now have that

$$\log^{-1}(x)=e^x, \text{ for all } x$$

What about $a^x$? Again, we know what $a^x$ is for rational $x$, based on trying to make $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ true for rational $x$ and $y$ if $f(x)=a^x$.

However, for irrational $x$, we will define $a^x$ based on a relationship to the function $e^x$. For $a>0$ we have

$$a^x=(\log^{-1}(\log{a}))^x=e^{x\log{a}}$$

We thus define, for $a>0$, that $a^x$ as $e^{x\log{a}}$ for irrational $x$. And then there is the following snippet in Spivak's *Calculus* that made me ask this question.

> Since $\log^{-1}$ takes on every positive value it is also easy to see
> that $a^x$ takes on every positive value.

Comment: $a^x$ doesn't takes all values. Did you mean "$a^x$ takes all *positive* values"?

Comment: Yes, I've corrected the question title.

Comment: There's a slight caveat: we must exclude $a=1$ because $\log(1)=0$.Otherwise, this is a trivial consequence of the following: for every function $f:\Bbb{R}\to X$, and for every non-zero $c\in\Bbb{R}$, the function $g:\Bbb{R}\to X$ defined as $g(x) =f(cx)$ has the same image as $f$. This is yet a consequence that if you compose a function its domain by a surjective map, then the image remains unchanged.

Comment: @peek-a-boo, why do we have to exclude $a=1$? $1^x=e^{x \log{1}}=e^{0}=1$. The  only exclusion I see is made at the beginning of the flow of ideas in the chapter, when the task was simply "find a differentiable $f$ such that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$", and that exclusion was that $f(1)\neq 0$. $f$ turned out to be $\exp(x)=\log^{-1}{x}$, so $\log^{-1}{1}\neq 0\implies 1\neq \log{0}$ is the restriction. But this restriction isn't even well-defined because $\log{0}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: I told you why it has to be excluded. If not, you don't hit all positive numbers. Even more directly, $1^x=1$ for all $x$, so it's a constant function, so obviously doesn't take on all positive numbers. This is also stated in the textbook.

Comment: Oh, yes, I actually forgot about the context: my original question. Yes, the statement that $\log^{-1}$ takes on every positive value requires $0<a<1$ or $a>1$, and this is present in the textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given, $a>0$, $e^{x \log a}$ is a function of $x$ defined over the real line. It is of the form: $f(x) = e^{cx}$, for some constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$. To show that this function takes all positive values, we need to show that for any positive real number, $y$, there is a real number $x$ such that $e^{x \log a} = y$. Using the definition of the logarithmic function, this is equivalent to: $x \log a = \log y$. Since $y>0$, we know $\log(y)$ is defined. Moreover, since $a>0$, $\log a$ is defined and not $0$. Hence, $x = \frac{\log y}{\log a}$ is a well defined real number. Thus, we have found the required $x$.

Comment: *"since $a>0$, $\log a$ is defined and not $0$"* that's not true. We must exclude $a=1$ (which actually is done in the text, though OP didn't state this restriction).

Comment: Yes, I agree. I should have excluded $a=1$.